# Have optional sub-variables in required Terraform variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, hcl

I have created a module corresponding to the [Azure Firewall Network Rule Collection](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/firewall_network_rule_collection). The module looks like this:

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_network_rule_collection" "fwnrc" {
  name                = "fwnrc-${var.name}"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  azure_firewall_name = var.azure_firewall_name
  priority            = var.priority
  action              = var.action

  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = var.rule != null ? [true] : []
    content {
      name                  = var.rule.name
      description           = var.rule.description
      source_addresses      = var.rule.source_addresses
      source_ip_groups      = var.rule.source_ip_groups
      destination_addresses = var.rule.destination_addresses
      destination_ip_groups = var.rule.destination_ip_groups
      destination_fqdns     = var.rule.destination_fqdns
      destination_ports     = var.rule.destination_ports
      protocols             = var.rule.protocols
    }
  }
}
```

The section of interest right now is the `dynamic "rule"`, which has a corresponding variable defined like this:

```
variable "rule" {
  type = object({
    name                  = string
    description           = string
    source_addresses      = list(string)
    source_ip_groups      = list(string)
    destination_addresses = list(string)
    destination_ip_groups = list(string)
    destination_fqdns     = list(string)
    destination_ports     = list(string)
    protocols             = list(string)
  })
}
```

I know that it is possible to make the `rule` variable "Optional" by setting its default value to `null`. I want to go one step deeper and make the sub-variables* optional/required. For instance, in the resource documentation it is written that one must specify *either* `*_addresses` **or** `*_ip_groups`. The docs also says `destination_fqdns` is optional.

** Is there an actual name for these?*

Since the `rule` variable is required by my module I get an error if I do not give explicit values to all sub-variables. My solution for now is to do the following:

```
module "firewall_network_rule_collection" {
  source = "/path/to/module"

  name                = "fwrc"
  azure_firewall_name = "afw"
  resource_group_name = "rg"
  priority            = 110
  action              = "Allow"

  rule = {
    description = "rule"
    name        = "rule"

    source_addresses = ["*"]
    source_ip_groups = null

    destination_ports = ["*"]
    destination_addresses = [
      "AzureContainerRegistry",
      "MicrosoftContainerRegistry",
      "AzureActiveDirectory"
    ]
    destination_fqdns     = null
    destination_ip_groups = null

    protocols = ["Any"]

  }

}
```

Note the `null` values. Can I get rid of these somehow?

--

I am using the following provider settings:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">=1.0.11"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=2.90.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [experimental "optional" object type](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/type-constraints#experimental-optional-object-type-attributes) is currently available if one opts in.

Add the following to your module:

```
terraform {
  experiments = [module_variable_optional_attrs]
}
```

This allows the following:

```
variable "rule" {
  type = object({
    name                  = string
    description           = optional(string)
    source_addresses      = optional(list(string))
    source_ip_groups      = optional(list(string))
    destination_addresses = optional(list(string))
    destination_ip_groups = optional(list(string))
    destination_fqdns     = optional(list(string))
    destination_ports     = optional(list(string))
    protocols             = optional(list(string))
  })
}
```

Hopefully this feature makes it to a fully supported part of the next release.

Comment: According to documentation, it has been experimental between v0.14 and v1.2, no reference to experimental in v1.3

Answer (score 0):

Without the experimental `optional()`, you can remove the `type` constraint and communicate the module user that a `map` with the specified attributes is expected.

Then in the code you have to check if an attribute is set or not.
Simplified example:

```
variable "rule" {
  # Type can't be specified, as even `map(any)` would enforce all entries to same type
  type = any
  # Some validation might be added for required attributes,
  # or just let the error flow though from code
}

# ...
  content {
    # Fails if `name` is not specified
    name = var.rule.name
    # Default to `null`
    description = lookup(var.rule, "description", null)

    # ...
  }
```

With the `lookup()` you can also add another default value to an attribute.

In case there are non-null default values or the defaults are constructed with other attributes, it might be cleaner to fill in the defaults using a local variable (similar to what is needed with the current `optional()` proposal).

For example:

```
locals {
  rule = merge(
    {
      description       = var.rule.name
      destination_fqdns = ["foo.example.com]
      source_addresses  = null
      # ...
    },
    var.rule
  )
}
```

Then you can always refer to the attributes with just the dot notation.